# Css class modify in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have this CSS class:

```
    .tooltip:hover > b {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        display: inline;
        margin-top:30px;
    }
```

Now, I need to change the display to none using jQuery. I tried

```
     $('.tooltip').find('b').css('display', 'none');
```

and

```
     $('.tooltip').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
     });
```

but niether are changing the display to none.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are your calls at the bottom of the page or wrapped in a dom ready check? `$(function(){ $('.tooltip b').hide(); }`

Comment: The question is not clear. Under what circumstances do you want the `<b>` to be hidden? What are the existing styles when the ".tooltip" element is not under the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tooltip').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('b').css('display', 'none');
     });
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried everything still doesn`t want to work :( not my code and its written like shit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.tooltip b').hover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
     });
```

Comment: He wants to hide the `<b>` element, not the tooltip element.

Comment: Press F12 and enable console and look if any error occur.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with `display`, nor do you need to do two-steps selection: one selector is enough.

Simply do:

```
$('.tooltip b').hide();
```

Comment: Its still not working...its not my code, I'm just fixing a bug. The .tooltip > b  is hidden and appear only when hover. And its a bug on iPad that I have fix only if I make the .tooltip:hover > b display:none; . I`m so annoyed

Comment: *"The .tooltip > b is hidden and appear only when hover."*: not according to your code. So you haven't shared all the relevant code. What about emulating the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/ and giving us a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

Here the reason: `.css('display', 'none');`

use `.css({'display' : 'none'});` make sure it is colon ":" but not a comma "," and they are inside curly braces.

Comment: nope. you`re wrong. 

http://api.jquery.com/css/ <-read. 

         .css('display', 'none'); is valid

Comment: yes. you use .css({'display': 'none'}); when you are formatting multiple-word properties